# Can I challenge a hiring decision?

Tags: human-resources, germany, rejection

I apologise if this was asked before. I couldn't find a suitable question in spite of searching all possible keywords.

I got rejected for an entry-level quantitative analyst position at one of the largest companies in Germany without an interview, even though I fulfilled all requirements. The rejection email came just a day later, so the rejection probably came from HR rather than the technical team.

I suspect that this decision violated the equal opportunity conditions, but I am not planning to be litigious about it. Being litigious wouldn't help me in any way. However, I would like my CV to be considered by the technical team or receive a concrete response on why I did not deserve a chance for an interview.

I found the recruiter on LinkedIn and tried to contact her. She has not yet responded. The recruitment page has a "Contact us" button. It seems like it is the only way for me to contact the company except for contacting them on social media.

Is there actually a way for me to bypass the HR or object to the HR decision?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think that being rejected for a job violated equal opportunity conditions? For entry level jobs there are going to be hundreds rejections per single opening. And honestly best advice I can give you is to move on and focus on other opportunities, unless you are Saul Goodman, you are not talking your way into that job after being rejected without even an interview.

Comment: Have you considered that they may have already found a candidate for the position and that is why you were rejected?

Comment: "But the job listing did not ask any knowledge of German." > did it list any language requirements? if it didn't, it might be assumed that speaking German is a requirement and it was just forgotten because it is selfevident to whomever wrote it. Subjectively, a lot of job listings leave that part out.

Comment: then you're lack of german was likely not the point. I know Teams and projects in Germany where the language spoken is English, and some people dont speak German at all.

Comment: You say you met all the requirements. Are they absolutely clear on your CV to a non-finance person? I know in my (STEM) hiring that I can't let my HR people make decisions on technical requirements. They just don't know all the lingo well. So, I have very few 'required', and put the technical stuff in 'desireds' that I get to rank...

Comment: A bunch of long answers are going to all say the same thing - “no.”

Comment: Why would they hire a Ph.D. for an entry level position when they can find dozens of other people that are a better fit? Do you require any type of Visa or immigration sponsorship?

Comment: Do you have any prior experience regarding job applications, in Germany?

Answer (score 13):

> Is there actually a way for me to bypass the HR or object to the HR decision?

#### No.

HR did not slip in there unnoticed and is now maliciously rejecting candidates. Whoever rejected you (you don't even know if it was HR), rejected you because it is *their job* to do so. The company *wants* them to do so. Otherwise they would not be in the position to do so.

You can be sad, that is natural.

You can disagree with their judgement call, but quite frankly, assuming you know better what they want for their job opening then they do seems a little weird.

Move on. If they don't want you, their loss, go work for their competitor.

Comment: I am sure HR did not act maliciously, because they don't have any reason to do so. But each job application takes about 45 minutes to complete for me. If I don't get a chance for an interview for a job I fulfil all the listed requirements, it means the job listing did not reflect what HR is expecting. This is what I am exploring.

Comment: @C.Koca you need to streamline you process, 45 minutes for application is a bit insane. And just because you match an ad didn't mean you match the actually job either. And that assumes that you actually do match the add, which honestly is far from given.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I prepared a standardised Latex template for the cover letter, that I enter the job ID, recruiter's name, company name etc. I just go over the intro and conclusion and match it for the company and even then it takes 45 min. Maybe it will be faster in the future.

Comment: If you didn't get an interview, it means they had enough other candidates that seemed "better". Or maybe even filled the role already. If you suspect something is wrong, every time you did not get an interview at large company, you will be in for a lot of disappointments. 45min is perfectly fine for an application in Germany, you are not supposed to send them out like spam. It seems you did everything right, but that doesn't mean the other 100-1000 people replying to that ad didn't. And you didn't make the cut, because the company cannot possible interview all of them.

Answer (score 12):

> I got rejected for an entry-level quantitative analyst position at one
> of the largest companies in Germany without an interview, even though
> I fulfilled all requirements. The rejection email came just a day
> later, so the rejection probably came from HR rather than the
> technical team.

From one of your comments:

> It asked for MINT graduates for a finance job for people with
> experience in Monte Carlo simulations. I have PhD in a MINT field and
> I have published several papers involving Monte Carlo simulations that
> gathered about a few hundred citations. So, I am trying to understand
> why HR did not care to pass my CV to the tech team.

One day is plenty of time to run it past the tech team. I have worked for places where resumes were passed every day, and other were we didn't see any until the posting closed.

From another of your comments:

> "However, after a thorough examination of your documents, we
> unfortunately have to inform you that we are currently unable to offer
> you a suitable position at COMPANY".

You also might have been over qualified. That will get a quick rejection.

Comment: @C.Koca - Why? Doing so is vital to the answer? In all honesty the clarity of those comments should be in the body of the question anyways.

Answer (score 9):

> Can I challenge a hiring decision?

It is unlikely you can do so in this case.

It is best to move on and apply for other jobs at other companies or even at the same company.

There are many reasons a company can reject a candidate without telling the candidate why they reject him/her.

---

You will find true stories about some of the most talented software programmers and engineers being rejected for either **non-sensical** or **unknown** reasons in the IT industry.

Then, these rejected engineers apply for more jobs and eventually they get offers with higher salary in the positions that fit their long-term career goals much better.

Some of these rejected engineers even found their own successful companies after facing **unknown** rejections. :-)

Answer (score 9):

If you write one of the largest companies in Germany, depending on what exactly you applied for, this may mean dozens or hundreds of other people have applied too.
They dont want to interview a hundred people though, so they reduce the number. You fullfill all the requirements, but 10 other people fullfill them better? -> You are out.

You have typos in your letter or CV -> you are out, take someone who doesnt have any typos.

etc, etc, etc...

This may not be totaly fair, but they only want to find someone suitable, and there will be more than one suitable applicant.

Any skilled recuiter will not give you any written response, other than:
We found a more suitable candidate.

To give you any other information may open them up to you suing them. Not nessecarily succesfully, but you may use it.
You proving in court that the candidate they ultimately took is less suitable than you is next to impossible.

If you dont want to be litigious, try to phone them. This does not leave a paper trail, and thus they might be willing to tell you something.
Tell them you want to improve, and if you may ask why you werent taken and what you could improve.
They may then informally tell you something useful.
Or they may tell you:
We found a more suitable candidate.

If they truly violated the equal opportunity conditions, they will not answer truthfully. If they didnt violate the equal opportunity conditions, they still might refuse to answer anyway, just for fear of litigation.

Comment: @C.Koca, You are right. Don't file a lawsuit in this case. It is a waste of time.

Comment: "You fullfill all the requirements, but 10 other people fullfill them better?" - this. Time and again, I am surprised by people who seem to take the listed requirements in a job ad as a verbatim list of exactly the list of things that will be useful for the job. Seriously, if we were to list every skill that is might be useful for a given job, and that may thus weigh positively when evaluating a candidate, in the ad, each of our ads would span at least 10 pages. And no-one would apply, as no-one fulfils exactly these requirements. The requirements are a rough guideline, nothing more.